# Why do I get NaN value in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Whilst I am doing cart in react, I have no idea why I keep getting NaN value - only from a specific object data.

When I have the following data list:

#1 ItemsList.js

```
export const ItemsList = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "VA-11 Hall-A: Cyberpunk Bartender Action",
    price: 110000,
    image: cover1,
    link: "https://store.steampowered.com/app/447530/VA11_HallA_Cyberpunk_Bartender_Action/?l=koreana",
  },
...
  {
    id: 6,
    name: "Limbus Company",
    price: 110000,
    image: cover6,
    link: "https://limbuscompany.com/",
  },
];
```

And the following code, please look at the comment line.

#2 Goods.jsx

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import "./Goods.css";
import { DataContext } from "../../components/context/DataContext";

export const Goods = (props) => {
  const { id, name, price, image, link } = props.shopItemProps;
  const { cartItems, addItemToCart, removeItemFromCart } =
    useContext(DataContext);
  const cartItemStored = cartItems[id];

  return (
    <div className="goods">
      <div className="goods-id">{id}</div>
      <img src={image} alt="thumbnail_image" className="goods-image" />
      <div className="goods-name">{name}</div>
      <div className="goods-price">${price}</div>
      <button>
        <a href={link} className="goods-link">
          Official Store Page
        </a>
      </button>
      <div className="cart-button">
        <button onClick={() => removeItemFromCart(id)}>-</button>
// ★Maybe here? but why do I get NaN only for id:6? Others work well.
        {cartItemStored > -1 && <> ({cartItemStored}) </>}
        <button onClick={() => addItemToCart(id)}>+</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

What should I do to solve NaN? There seems to be no way to make that value as int in this case. Or do you see any problem from the above code block?

### Edited

Sorry for confusing you. Here are the additional code related.

#3. DataContext.js (where cartItems state exists)

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from "react";
import { ItemsList } from "../ItemsList";

export const DataContext = createContext(null);

const getDefaultCart = () => {
  let cart = {};
  for (let i = 1; i < ItemsList.length; i++) {
    cart[i] = 0;
  }
  return cart;
};

export const DataContextProvider = (props) => {
  const [cartItems, setCartItems] = useState(getDefaultCart);

  const checkoutTotalSum = () => {
    let totalAmount = 0;
    for (const item in cartItems) {
      if (cartItems[item] > 0) {
        let itemInfo = ItemsList.find((product) => product.id === Number(item));
        totalAmount += cartItems[item] * itemInfo.price;
      }
    }
    return totalAmount;
  };

  const addItemToCart = (itemId) => {
    setCartItems((prev) => ({ ...prev, [itemId]: prev[itemId] + 1 }));
  };

  const removeItemFromCart = (itemId) => {
    setCartItems((prev) => ({ ...prev, [itemId]: prev[itemId] - 1 }));
  };

  const updateCartItemCount = (newAmount, itemId) => {
    setCartItems((prev) => ({ ...prev, [itemId]: newAmount }));
  };

  const contextValue = {
    cartItems,
    addItemToCart,
    removeItemFromCart,
    updateCartItemCount,
    checkoutTotalSum,
  };

  // console.log(cartItems);

  return (
    <DataContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
      {props.children}
    </DataContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Comment: [Here's some documentation on how to create a React snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338538/1377002).

Comment: Where NaN is being shown?

Comment: It's difficult to debug this because you don't identify where the `NaN` is appearing, what debugging _you've_ done to resolve this, and what is happening in the code you _haven't_ added like `addItemToCart` which could be causing the issue.

Comment: Also, it would be nice if you show us how `cartItems` look like.

Comment: May be add some more code snippets to help us understand the full picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is in the function you are using to set the initial value of `cartItems`, more specifically, in the `for` loop. This line is the culprit: `i < ItemsList.length`, when in your case, it should be `i <= ItemsList.length`. Why? because you are not including the last element of `ItemsList` on the `cart` object (you are initializing the `i` counter with 1 and `ItemsList`'s length is 6).

So, when you call `addItemToCart`:

```
const addItemToCart = (itemId) => {
  setCartItems((prev) => ({ ...prev, [itemId]: prev[itemId] + 1 }));
};
```

And try to update the value corresponding to the last element of `ItemsList` which is 6 in `cartItems`, you're getting: `'6': undefined + 1` because again, you did skip the last element in the `for` loop. This results in `NaN`.

You also have the option of initializing `i` with 0 and preserve this line: `i < ItemsList.length`, or:

```
for (let i = 1; i < ItemsList.length + 1; i++) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: This answers the OP's question, but you might want to add a little more clarity as to why the last element is not included - the indexing starts at `1` instead of `0` in the for loop. You can either start the indexing at `0` or adjust the comparison operator to include the ceiling. Let them know the choices.

Comment: @KarthikSivasubramaniam thanks for the observation, I updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the kind explanation ivanatias, and Karthik Sivasubramaniam. In my case, I choose to go 0. It would kill me slowly if I did not understand the reason 'why' I got that return, NaN. Again, thank you! （＾∀＾●）ﾉｼ